# Overwrite data in one table with data from another if two keys match

Tags: sql, sas

EDIT: I'm using the PROC SQL functionality in SAS.

I'm trying to overwrite data in a primary table with data in a secondary table if two IDs match. Basically, there is a process modifying certain values associated with various IDs, and after that process is done I want to update the values associated with those IDs in the primary table. For a very simplified example:

Primary table:

```
PROD_ID          PRICE           IN_STOCK    
   1              5.25              17   
   2             10.24             200       [...additional fields...]
   3              6.42             140   
  ...
```

Secondary table:

```
PROD_ID          PRICE           IN_STOCK
   2             11.50             175   
   3              6.42             130
```

And I'm trying to get the new Primary table to look like this:

```
PROD_ID          PRICE           IN_STOCK
   1              5.25              17   
   2             11.50             175       [...additional fields...]
   3              6.42             130   
  ...
```

So it overwrites certain columns in the primary table if the keys match.

In non-working SQL code, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PRIMARY_TABLE (PRICE, IN_STOCK)
SELECT PRICE, IN_STOCK
FROM SECONDARY_TABLE
WHERE SECONDARY_TABLE.PROD_ID = PRIMARY_TABLE.PROD_ID
```

Is this possible to do in one statement like this, or will I have to figure out some workaround using temporary tables (which is something I'm trying to avoid)?

EDIT: None of the current answers seem to be working, although it's probably my fault - I'm using PROC SQL in SAS and didn't specify, so is it possible some of the functionality is missing? For example,  the "FROM" keyword doesn't turn blue when using UPDATE, and throws errors when trying to run it, but the UPDATE and SET seem fine...

Comment: In SAS PROC SQL, you can't update two values simultaneously from one select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer in SAS PROC SQL is simply to do it as a left join and use COALESCE, which picks the first nonmissing value:

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
run;
data class_updates;
input name $ height weight;
datalines;
Alfred 70 150
Alice 59 92
Henry 65 115
Judy 66 95
;;;;
run;


proc sql;
create table class as select C.name, coalesce(U.height,C.height) as height, coalesce(U.weight,C.weight) as weight
    from class C
    left join class_updates U
    on C.name=U.name;
quit;
```

In this case though the SAS solution outside of SQL is superior in terms of simplicity of coding.

```
data class;
update class class_updates(in=u);
by name;
run;
```

This does require both tables to be sorted.  There are a host of different ways of doing this (hash table, format lookup, etc.) if you have performance needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to insert new data?  Or update existing rows?  If updating, join the tables:

```
UPDATE PT
SET
    PT.PRICE = ST.PRICE,
    PT.IN_STOCK = ST.IN_STOCK
FROM
    PRIMARY_TABLE PT JOIN SECONDARY_TABLE ST ON PT.PROD_ID = ST.PROD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO PRIMARY_TABLE (PRICE, IN_STOCK) VALUES
    (SELECT PRICE, IN_STOCK
    FROM SECONDARY_TABLE
    JOIN PRIMARY_TABLE ON SECONDARY_TABLE.PROD_ID = PRIMARY_TABLE.PROD_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would have to use an INSERT statement is if there are `ID`s present in the secondary table and not present in the primary table.  If this is not the case then use a regular UPDATE statement.  If it is the case then use the following:

```
INSERT INTO PRIMARY_TABLE (ID, PRICE, IN_STOCK)
SELECT ID, PRICE, IN_STOCK
FROM SECONDARY_TABLE s
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PRICE = s.PRICE, IN_STOCK = s.IN_STOCK
```